# How to implement Immersive mode in android app that was built using ionic framework?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my android app which was built using ionic framework, there is a problem in implementing immersive mode.
The problem is my screen is not scrolling when keypad is appeared, after removing the style
`<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>.` This property is used to fit the screen in between status bar and navigation bar.
The reason why I have removed this property is, because if it is there then the screen will fit in between status and navigation bar, and when immersive mode is activated status and navigation bars will get hide, but the area that is occupied by status and navigation bars will appear blank.

This is the code used for immersive sticky mode.

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     if (hasFocus) {
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
     }
 }
```

If you have any idea about this problem, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I just used `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>` on my config.xml (Ionic config)

Comment: can you please tell how you did it ?